# How to exclude certain test in VSTS using playlist files?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, msbuild, mstest

I am facing an issue to exclude certain test case in vsts online, I don't want to do changes to test class or a function, I know [Ignore] will do the same, but I want to keep them in a separate playlist file and run the test based on the playlist I have selected. I tried the bellow in cmd and that didn't work.

```
mstest.exe /testmetadata:test.playlist
```

any better way to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you consider the "Test Filter Criteria" option?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk : Can we include playlist files there? The big problem here is we have 3000 ++ test cases and can't add TestCategory to all of them like bellow.  [TestCategory("Bugs"), TestMethod]